# Don't allow reboot for PowerShell command

Tags: powershell

I have quite a large bat file that launches PowerShell to install Windows Roles and Features like this:

```
POWERSHELL.EXE -Command "&{Import-Module ServerManager; Add-WindowsFeature ...
```

This works fine, but in some cases PS will prompt "Do you want to restart the computer to complete this operation now?". Is there something I can add to this command to prevent that prompt? There are a few other things that I do after this and then will reboot anyway. This is part of a large unattended operation and I would like it to allow me to handle reboots myself.
Thank you.

Comment: did you try "Add-WindowsFeature ... -norestart"?

Comment: I recommend looking into `boxstarter`: http://boxstarter.org/

Comment: @almog.ori, No I did not. But that does the trick. If you change your comment to an answer I will accept.  Thanks!

Comment: The subject line "Don't allow reboot for PowerShell command" seems incorrect. I think you mean "Don't prompt for reboot after PowerShell command"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you may be missing the "-norestart" switch on the Add-WindowsFeature cmdlet

> Add-WindowsFeature ... -norestart

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've discovered, the answer to this question is: you can't. The `-norestart` is only available for `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature cmdlet`.

You can only use `-Restart` with `Add-WindowsFeature`. If you leave it out, my experience is that the server will not be restarted but you may not be able to use whatever you installed until the server is rebooted.

`-norestart` with `Add-WindowsFeature` will probably break the command and thats probably why you don't get a prompt anymore.